# Add C++ book list to tag wiki FAQ list?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

There is a [list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on SO, which I consider an excellent resource. It's also linked from the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag wiki, but in my opinion, the link is somewhat "buried" in the text. The tag wiki also has a bullet point list of FAQ. Would it make sense to repeat link to the book question in that list as well?

I think it would increase the likelihood of someone who's just skimming throught he tag wiki actually finding the book list. However, I would prefer to learn the C++ SO subcommunity opinion on this before doing the edit.

Comment: Check out room 10 where the C++ guru's hang out.

Comment: This implies people actually read tag wikis.

Comment: This implies anybody in "room 10" is anything close to a guru. Or that what happens there is anything close to "hanging out"...

Comment: The books are a learning resource, that list never taught anybody squat.  It is in fact actively harmful, it promotes the drastically broken idea that reading just one is enough.  Not sure why the C++ community likes to keep it around, I think it is just so they can easily skip book recommendation questions.  Which are off-topic but are asked in comments anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, of course I didn't mean anyone actually learns something from the list itself. But I'd say it's a resource for learning anyway. I generally use this list in addition to answering a question, along the lines of "this is a rather basic question, you might want to pick up a [good book] to learn more."

Comment: @HansPassant: I think the intention is to promote the excellent idea that reading at least one is orders of magnitude better than reading _none_!

Comment: Hmya, however appropriate such a comment might seem to be (and it is but a hair over "Google it"), it is *never* appropriate to anybody else that reads it.  We're not running a forum here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go for it but don't expect it to make a blind bit of difference. Very few people read tag wikis, least of all the sort of people who didn't bother to read a C++ book before storming in and asking their introductory question about `i++ = ++i + ++i`.

Comment: Also, the Tag Wiki sucks for SEO.