# Can the [c++] tag be removed from Meta StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, meta

There's only a single [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289659/add-c-book-list-to-tag-wiki-faq-list) that uses it validly (I have removed it meanwhile), but it's not really adding value for research here.

The only effect of this tag may be that users feel encouraged to ask c++ programming related questions on Meta-SO.

Comment: Yeah, let us start on meta to get rid of that tag ...

Comment: Voted to migrate to meta.meta.so...

Comment: @rene Should tag burination requests for Meta StackOverflow posted at [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is fine here...

Comment: Meta-tags aren't really tags on meta. At least not tag-wise. Though certainly a tag on meta can be a meta-tag. How meta is that??

Comment: Why not remove it on the *main* site? THINK OUT OF THE BOX