# What is the procedure for burninating a tag on Meta.SO?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-system

I am well aware of the general [Burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) for tags. Does this process also apply to tags on Meta Stack Overflow? If not, is there a specific procedure for burninating an unneeded tag on Meta or is each case handled in whatever way the denizens of Meta feel is most appropriate at the time?

I am *not* talking about so-called ["Meta tags"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351636/what-is-the-appropriate-reaction-to-meta-tags) on the main site such as "beginner", but the tags that are used on questions posted to the Meta Stack Overflow site.

Comment: You simply ask on meta. The procedure to get things removed from meta itself are less ceremonial ... example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303838/can-the-c-tag-be-removed-from-meta-stackoverflow

Comment: Obviously, you post a burninate request on meta.meta.stackoverflow.com. Such as "Burninate burninate-request".

Comment: @Lundin where do you ask if you want to burninate a tag on meta.meta.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @RobertColumbia We might have to write a recursive function to solve this problem.

Comment: @Lundin I want to suggest that we burninate a tag on meta.meta.meta.meta.stackoverflow.com, but I'd first like to ask a question about how to ask a question about setting up a burnination request there. Where should I ask?

Answer (score 17):

**It is broadly [the same](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).**

The primary difference is that we don't ever need to make these [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), since there's no need to get it in front of the larger audience of Stack Overflow users. It's sufficient (if not better) to limit it to Meta regulars weighing in on the proposal, since they're the most knowledgeable about how tagging works on Meta.

Other things are all the same:

- Don't waste your (or anyone else's) time removing tags that aren't causing any harm (or adding tags for no benefit whatsoever). *"If it looks like pointless busywork, it probably is pointless busywork..."*
- If there is a very small number of questions (Meta is on a smaller scale than main, so say < 20–25), and you've conferred with at least one other knowledgeable Meta user as a sanity check, then you can go ahead and remove the tag.
- If there is a larger number of questions, then you need to go ahead and post a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) (also tagged with [meta](/questions/tagged/meta), of course), providing with your rationale for why the tag should be removed, and give the community a chance to weigh in before you just start *doing* stuff. Never misinterpret apathy as consensus.

Like rene says, there can and will naturally be a bit less ceremony on Meta, but **vigilante retagging/burnination is a total mess, and it's no less messy on Meta than it is on main**. If anything, it's *more* annoying because of the site's smaller size, and *more* dangerous because of how Meta abuses the Q&A model as a discussion platform—plenty of things here are counter-intuitive. The process exists because it solves many problems and prevents difficult-to-repair errors. I simply won't tolerate it being ignored altogether.

Answer (score 5):

No, the [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) was specifically tailored for the removal of tags from main. That process isn't meant nor a good fit to be applied to Meta as it needs to cater for tags with a lot of question or complex cross-domain topics.

There is no specific procedure to get rid of an unneeded tag on Meta. Just ask a meta question, tag it [burnination-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burnination-request), make clear it concerns Meta.SO and address the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191). More often then not the number of questions are low so cleaning up can be done in one seating once consensus is reached.

There is no need for ceremony on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

It's no different than it would be on the main site.  Admittedly, burninating tags on Meta is much *rarer*, but there would be no reason not to follow the same process for their removal.

Comment: I don't think a Meta burnination would need the post to be featured on Main. So it is different ...

Comment: @rene:  My belief here that, if a meta tag did need to be burninated, we'd still have the same pool of burninators available to us and  we'd want to ensure that senseless tag edits didn't occur.  I don't see a reason why our rigor would suddenly drop just because we're on Meta.

Comment: Okay, but the process the OP linked to needs to be tailored then.