# Should we add book lists to tag wiki with links to online shops?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, external-links

Recently several tag wikis on Stack Overflow were edited by Amd:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12948476
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12951282
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12951229
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12948811
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12948682
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12948746

He added lists of books, which may be fine. But there are external links to various online shops and publishers: shop.oreilly.com, apress.com, amazon.com, packt, etc.

Should we recommend any shop by giving link to it, when we list books in tag wikis? Should we give link to publisher? To shop?

Why are some links converted to the "rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/" referral program?

Comment: as long as they don't add their own affilation id I don't see much harm, providing they are linking to the publisher site or legit bookstore like amazon. The link conversion happens by Stack Overflow as they have their own affiliation deal where a click doesn't cover the cost having that conversion in the first place.

Comment: related with regard to rads: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277803/please-take-away-the-google-juice-from-rads-stackoverflow-com and on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/30394/158100)

Answer (score 2):

There are list of books also, exactly in this style.
In many wikis the list of books are in the wiki section;
just when there are long lists, some wikis added a separate post.

The link is provided to a publisher site or legitimate bookstore like Amazon.

Editing the post yourself to change the formatting to be correct is a perfectly fine solution, and I encourage any user to do so. If a user doesn't understand why you made the change, explain it to them or link them to a relevant question here on Meta.

Also see: [Add C++ book list to tag wiki FAQ list?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289659/add-c-book-list-to-tag-wiki-faq-list?rq=1)

By the way I don't recommend any shop.

See new Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua/info

Comment: How did you select books for adding into popular tags? How many books should be listed there? Should we prefer newer books, or older books for something like C or JS or mature languages like lisp? If you talk about library, why not link to worldcat/OCLC (it knows some local libraries)? If there is "free to download" pdf or torrent of book, should we give it or magnet link? Wikipedia for example internally links ISBN to special landing with lot of links:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-7695-1605-X

Comment: C/C++ tag wikis has no direct links to any of books; they links to stackoverflow questions with lists of books; check also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/

Comment: Strictly speaking, the books you suggested for STL are not even on-topic for that tag as STL != C++-standard-library (the latter being the thing the books talk about). For more information on that, see the tag wiki of STL.

Comment: @baum-mit-augen: Chapter 6: The Standard Template Library

Comment: Amd, can you add publisher name and year to the book entry format? There are good publishers, and there are outdated books...

Comment: @osgx How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua/info